# Iterate over slice of strings and add 10 to each string

Tags: string, go, slice

I'm trying to iterate over a slice of strings and add 10 to each string, e.g:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func addTen(ss *[]string) {
    for _, s := range *ss {
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%s10", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    ss := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    addTen(&ss)
    fmt.Println(ss)
}
```

The compiler is complaining that `s` is not defined.

Comment: With the addition of `import "fmt"`, the program compiles without error.

Comment: @ThunderCat yes, but it doesn't add the 10 to the strings of ss .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to append "10" to each slice element:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func addTen(ss []string) {
    for i, s := range ss {
        ss[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%s10", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    ss := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    addTen(ss)
    fmt.Println(ss)
}
```

Key points:

- Assign the string to the slice element.  The code `s = fmt.Sprintf("%s10", s)` assigns to local variable `s`, which is discarded.
- The code in this answer passes a slice value instead of passing a pointer to a slice.  It's not necessary to pass a pointer in this situation, nor is there a performance benefit to passing a pointer. It's simpler to just pass the value.

Comment: can you explain why passing a slice instead of a pointer is more idiomatic?

Comment: It's not necessary to pass a pointer in this situation, nor is there a performance benefit to passing a pointer.  The idiomatic approach is to pass by value.

Comment: What if the slice is big, is there no performance gain to pass by reference/pointer?

Comment: A slice value contains a pointer to the backing array, length and capacity. The size of a slice value is always three machine words.

Comment: when, if ever, would you pass in a slice by reference?

Comment: Use a pointer argument when the function modifies the caller's slice value. That said, it's typical to return a slice from the function instead of taking a pointer argument.  See [bullt-in append](https://godoc.org/builtin#append), [strconv.AppendXXXX](https://godoc.org/strconv#AppendBool) for examples.

Comment: But addTen modifies caller’s slice so why not pass in a pointer?

Comment: It modifies the backing array, not the slice value (pointer,length, capacity).